# What is the best way to view a ticket by ticket number?

Tags: sabre

Which API(s) would be the most ideal to use if you'd like to fetch Sabre ticket data by ticket number (not PNR)?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the VCR_DisplayLLSRQ soap/xml web service to obtain ticket and coupon data.

Sample java code for creating a request to lookup a ticket using the ticket number is below...

```
VCRDisplayRQ vcrDisplayRQ = new VCRDisplayRQ()
  .withVersion("2.2.2")
  .withSearchOptions(new SearchOptions()
    .withTicketing(new Ticketing()
      .withETicketNumber(ticketNo)
      ))
  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the raw XML.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:mes="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            {{sessionToken}}
         </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <mes:MessageHeader>
            <mes:From>
                <mes:PartyId>YOURNAME</mes:PartyId>
            </mes:From>
            <mes:To>
                <mes:PartyId>SABRE</mes:PartyId>
            </mes:To>
            <mes:CPAId>1234</mes:CPAId>
            <mes:ConversationId>1234</mes:ConversationId>
            <mes:Service>eTicketCouponLLSRQ</mes:Service>
            <mes:Action>eTicketCouponLLSRQ</mes:Action>
        </mes:MessageHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>      
      <eTicketCouponRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.0.0">              
       <Ticketing eTicketNumber="0067771112222"/>       
     </eTicketCouponRQ>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```